# Multiple users with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I have 4 different type of users. Every type have own role and additional attributes. 
User is parent, and 3 inheritors.

Also I use Spring Data.

In which way I can implement UserDetailsService to use 4 different types of users?

Now I have:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

And

```
public class Employee extends User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private String fullName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
    private Set<Project> projects;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private Set<Task> tasks;

}
```

And other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking about `UserDetailsService` I assume that you use `Spring Security`. If you only need to authenticate/authorize users, I'm not sure you need the full user management the `UserDetailsService` offers. It may be enough to define a single `AuthenticationProvider` and to the query here

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                // Do you database query here
                ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"));  // list of roles from database 
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(),
                           authentication.getCredentials(), authorities);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                return true;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This example is inline and you should probably make the `AuthenticationProvider` a real class.

The `AuthenticationProvider` is called with an unauthenticated `Authentication`, which has been created by a filter, typically `BasicAuthenticationFilter` or `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. After this, the `Authentication` is given to the `ProviderManager` which ask each of the `AuthenticationProvider` if they can authenticate this type of `Authentication` (this is what the *supports()* method is for). Once a suitable `AuthenticationProvider` is found, it is asked to authenticate — This is where you do your database lookup and find the roles from the database, and construct a new `Authentication` with the list of `GrantedAuthorities` based on the roles from the database.

Be aware that you should put "ROLE_" in front of the roles (unless you store them like that), otherwise it will not work with the declarative access configured using `HttpSecurity`

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/","/home").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
         // more lines 
}
```

Here ADMIN maps to the `GrantedAuthority` ROLE_ADMIN.